# Python convention for separating files

Tags: python

Im not positive on the terminology here, so that may explain why searching on my own yielded no results.

I was just curious if there is a widely accepted, general method to writing a module in python. Obviosuly people prefer splitting things into segmented .py scripts, importing when needed, and packing it all into a folder.

What I want to know: Is there a general method to how/when/why we stop writing things together in one .py and begin a new one (And i mean other than obvious things like... one script .py for the main job, and then a preferences.py to handle reading/writing prefs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split your code into multiple modules when it begins to be unwieldy to keep it all in one module.  This is to some extent a matter of taste.  Note that it may unwieldy for the code author (i.e., file is too big to navigate easily) or for the user of the library (e.g., too many unrelated functions/classes jammed together in the same namespace, hard to keep track of them).

Comment: Alright thanks, this is more or less what i thought - it's usually somewhat obvious when it feels you should separate things. I just wanted to make sure theres not standard behind it. Thanks!